# Check custom grammar input text field

Tags: angular, validation, input, grammar

I have a custom grammar like this:

```
rule: <expression> {<op><expression>}
expression: <Object>[<property>] is <State>
property: key=value
State: active | inactive | valid .....
```

The grammar may change is not finished but that is not the problem.

I am currently working on an application based on angular2 and it's doing great so far but now I want to give an user the possibility to define rules himself with like an input text field or something like that.

My idea is that the input from the user is checked that it is conform with this grammar above and then I want to use the defined rules to apply them on an object.

Or maybe the input to the input field is given and the user has to choose. Like if you give a hint under the textfield where the user can choose or something like that.

Maybe somebody dealt already with such a problem and can lead me in the right direction. Every hint is helping.

Comment: This is really broad, and it sounds like you might be asking "what are good javascript/angular tools to build a parser with", which would be out of scope for SO. (See [ask]). (But you could look at jison, if that's of any help.)

Comment: Yes I know that my question is not well formed and I tried to be as concrete as possible. And thanks for the jison I think this will work :)

Comment: https://nearley.js.org/ is the way to go. Can be imported in Angular and has a awesome documentation and community.